# Azure Resource Management REST API for Bot Framework DirectLine Channel Configuration

Tags: azure, bots, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to add a Site to my DirectLine channel in my Azure Bot Registration via the REST APIs.  When I perform a GET against the following ARM REST URL, I get a JSON payload with any existing sites listed.

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{azure.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{MyResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/{MyBotHandle}/channels/DirectLineChannel?api-version=2017-12-01

If I then take the JSON output from the GET call and add a Site to it like this...

`{
  "id": "/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/{BotHandle}/channels/DirectLineChannel",
  "name": "{BotHandle}/DirectLineChannel",
  "type": "Microsoft.BotService/botServices/channels",
  "etag": "W/\"8e7678d65f7dbeea8863f0c68af75f606/6/2018 6:31:37 PM\"",
  "location": "global",
  "properties": {
    "properties": {
      "DirectLineEmbedCode": null,
      "sites": [
        {
          "siteId": "uXuynMwVIBI",
          "siteName": "Default Site",
          "key": "uXuynMwVIBI.cwA.ve8.m2IbJ0McgjmxAq8vlZ1ZY1jAFdpdQj14GbgrS4z-qpA",
          "key2": "uXuynMwVIBI.cwA.gXE.4aZw5_DIJuLPsQ2zjIYSCMztTxUxNpX4trwfO-6Gb9k",
          "isEnabled": true,
          "isV1Enabled": true,
          "isV3Enabled": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "etag": "W/\"8e7678d65f7dbeea8863f0c68af75f606/6/2018 6:31:37 PM\"",
    "channelName": "DirectLineChannel",
    "location": "global",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
  }
}`

... and then perform a PUT against the same initial URL, I get the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred. Exception: 'Microsoft.Bot.Schema.APIException: Empty service error response. ID: \r\n   at Intercom.Channels.Models.Shared.TimeLimitedConfigHttpClient`1.<GetFromResponseAsync>d__20.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Intercom.Channels.Models.Shared.TimeLimitedConfigHttpClient`1.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Intercom.Channels.Models.Shared.ConfigApi`1.<PutAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Intercom.ResourceProvider.Channels.ArmChannelManager.d__2`2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Intercom.ResourceProvider.DataProviders.ChannelResourceDataProvider.d__5.MoveNext()'.

I noticed this JSON looks like an ARM template as well so I tried adding it to a deployment and I get the exact same error above.  It provisions the bot and then I get an InternalServerError when it's provisioning the DirectLineChannel.  The Operation details link gives me the above error.

Any thoughts on how to do this?  Am I way off?

Thanks!